# Error downloading a File using JSF and Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an entity like this

```
@Entity
public class myFiles  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idmyFiles;


    @Lob   
    private File myFile;

    getters and setters...
```

I have an upload form that seems to work, when I upload a file I can see it in the postgtes table.

IN the form (I am using primefaces) I have this

```
<p:fieldset id="myFiles" class="recuadro" legend = "Upload a fileos">
    <p:fileUpload value="#{abmBean.fichero}" mode="simple" />
    <p:commandButton id="btnSubir" ajax="false" process="@all" update="@all"
        action="#{abmBean.uploadFile()}" value="Subir" />
</p:fieldset>
```

This is the method that uploads the file

```
public void uploadFile() {
    File destFile = new File("/tmp/"+fichero.getFileName());
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(fichero.getInputstream(), destFile);

    /* Then I just create a myFile object F and just F.setFile(destFile) */
}
```

It seems to work

To download the file I have this method

```
public downloadFile(int id) {
    /* the int id is the id of the myfile object F */

    /* I retrieve from the database the F object and then this*/
    File fichero = new File("/tmp/"+F.getFile.getName());

    FileUtils.copyFile(F.getFile, fichero);

    Faces.sendFile(fichero, true);
}
```

This works just fine and I have the file back

But the problem is this, I realize that the file I uploaded was also copied to the /tomcat7/bin folder andif I remove the file from there then when I want to dowload it I get a fileNotFoundException.

All I need is to be able to provide the user the file from the database

I am using Tomcat7, Java 1.6 (yes pretty old) Primefaces 6, Postgresql 9.1 and JSF2 on a Debian

Comment: Your title is misleading, I don't see any OmniFaces component but rather PrimeFaces (as stated in your tags). Also, please check if your backing bean managing the file upload has a [`@MultipartConfig` annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html). On the other side, please check the default upload folder in your PrimeFaces configuration ([documentation link, page 223](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_1.pdf)). I assume that the getter in the `myFiles` entity is fetching from the correct folder

Comment: Thanks I changed the title, My backingbean has no @MultipartConfig , I will be cheking the manual page you suggested

Comment: The file is in the database as a binary not as a string path

Comment: So the file only ends up in /tomcat7/bin when downloading the file?  Then all the uploadingen code in your Q is irrelevant. Please Barrow doen the problem. Postgress is 99.999 percent not related.

Comment: As Kukeltje mentions, the file in your database is not related to your problem. I suspect a misconfiguration of PrimeFaces temporary folder or something like that. How about the `F.getFile` in `FileUtils.copyFile(F.getFile, fichero);`? where does it refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the answers, I found the error.

I thought that a File was a binary containing the file and I thought the file was stored in the database, but I was wrong, the File is an abstract and stores only some metadata and the file path, the file itself needs to be stored and retrieved from the disk.

I will have to modify my system to use a byte[] to save the actual binary, wich is so sad because then Ill need to make a lot of procedures to store and retrieve them.

Thanks again for the answers, I learned a lot from them